# error System.InvalidCastException Forms (droid builds then crashes, ios is fine)

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.droid

My app worked fine. no updates... now this error is thrown right at droid simulator launch.

error System.InvalidCastException Forms (droid builds then crashes, ios is fine)

public partial class App : global::Xamarin.Forms.Application {

```
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "0.0.0.0")]
    private void InitializeComponent() {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(App));
    }
}
```

tried: clean, build, exit, restart computer, making sure my packages are all the same versions and on main,droid,and ios.

Comment: Could you post the Exception's full stack trace?

Comment: the stack trace for the exception is blank. I figured out the issue and I think there is only one real solution. I tried to get an older version of visual studios for mac... but microsoft would make me pay 500 to get the version i need (I looked around a lot "visual studio mac community 7.3.2")... my plugins have packages have been unsupported for some time and when I get rid of functions using those packages it works. I am only using these packages on my droid hence only droid is failing. I believe the solution is to find packages that are and will be supported. xlabs and xam.plugins.messages

Answer (score 0):

ok sooo. after attempting to find non deprecated packages to handle the issues. re-creating the app with everything updated (sdk, mono, packages, visual studio, etc..) I discovered that many packages have issues with being updated unless you update them in the right order. and with all the matching project focus, etc... xlabs still seems to work even thought it is no longer managed as of 2016.